# How to set a custom background color to UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicolor

I was wondering about different types of code for changing the background colour of the button. In my project, I am using:

```
button4.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

But it only gives me a restricted amount of colour options since it is `UIColor`. I was wondering if I can write a different piece of code to have more flexibility in the color of the button.

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: "restricted amount of colour options since it is UIColor" do you mean that you have an rgb that you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it only gives me a restricted amount of colour options since it is
>   `UIColor`.

That would be correct when working with the predefined static colors. However, no doubt that you can get another color which is none of the predefined ones.

For instance, consider you have a custom rgb color that you want to use in your app (the button background color), as: `red: 100 green: 44 blue: 63`, You could get it by using:

[`init(red:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init)

> Initializes and returns a color object using the specified opacity and
>   RGB component values.

as follows:

```
let myCustomRGBColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 44.0/255.0, blue: 63.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Note that the values are divided on 255.0 because rgb values for the UIColor are between 0 and 1.

Also, note that [`UIColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/) has many other [initializers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor#1658494) for creating a custom color object.

Comment: Great that is exactly what I need. In addition to your information, the decimal point is unnecessary in all the RGB options except for the alpha.

Comment: @AntonyD Glad to help. The decimal point *is* necessary at least for the 255, 44/255 = 0 but 44/255.0 is not :)